# Missing `tendermint/libs/db` when updating to new version of cosmos sdk

Tags: blockchain, tendermint

Updating cosmos-sdk from v0.35 to post v0.36 (cosmos-sdk@v0.36.0-rc1) () for new features. Got error because a package path wasn't working anymore:

```
Cannot load github.com/tendermint/tendermint/libs/db: cannot find module providing pacakge github.com/tendermint/tendermint/libs/db
```

[image: Missing module]

Comment: Hopefully we can get a cosmos network/sdk dedicated tag or even [SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122619/cosmos/122872#122872)

Answer (score 3):

This is because tendermint moved the `dbm` to a seperate module path.

do:

`$ go get github.com/tendermint/tm-db`

and replace:

`dbm "github.com/tendermint/tendermint/libs/db"`

whith:

`dbm "github.com/tendermint/tm-db"`

for your imports

Comment: There are potentially additional steps for other packages/modules/dependencies for getting upgraded fully to v0.36. I will add more going through this Q&A style.

Comment: Additionally when upgrading the sdk the genesis file generator method was moved from the `gaiad` pacakge to `genutils`. This means replacing  `"github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/cmd/gaia/init"` imports with `"github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/x/genutil"` when generating genesis file through the `init` command.